# Dereferencing a pointer to a structure

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I recently encountered this question.

A singly linked list was created, the node for the list looked like

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* link;
};
```

The list was created using add at head, the list looks like

100->200->300

The display function was written as

```
void display(struct node* head)
{
    while(head != NULL)
    {
        printf ("%d", *head);
        head=head->next;
    }
}
```

Is this a legal way of accessing the data in the list? I tied it against the GCC compiler, it threw a warning but it worked. Would it lead to errors for some cases?

Comment: What was the warning?  (To be clear, the answers highlight what the problem is, but the warning should be included in this question.  The warning may help future users find the question and answer, and, once it's added to the question, it will probably become apparent that the tags about data structures and (singly) linked lists probably aren't so important for this question.)

Answer (score 5):

```
printf ("%d", *head);
```

should be

```
printf ("%d", head->data);
```

then the compiler warning should go away. Your code worked by chance
(or by accident, as @alk commented)
 because `data` is
the first member of `struct node`. It probably depends on how struct arguments are
passed to the printf function. In any case, it is wrong.

Comment: I normally use head->data, this was asked during the hiring process for a company and I was wondering whether the answer would be error or the correct output, considering this test was a paper based objective test.

Comment: @user1276290: It depends on the "calling conventions" used on the platform. It might also fail if `*head` is followed by more printf arguments. In any case, it is wrong code using undefined behaviour.